# laravel does not load styles while passing value with urls

Tags: laravel, url, routes

im using a laravel 5.4 and i have a problem with urls, when i send value with urls like `http://localhost:8000/Music/{id}` , laravel does not load styles but if use url without value to get that view it loads styles properly, it also does not load styles if an slash get added to end of url like `http://localhost:8000/videos/` but without that slash `http://localhost:8000/videos` works without problem ..sorry i cant speak english good.

here is my code :

`Route::get('Music/{id}','homeController@Music');`

```
public function Music(music $item)
{
    return view('music',['item'=>$item]);
}
```

this works by route model binding properly and does what i want but when it returns music blade file it does not load styles that i linked but if use this instead :

```
Route::get('Music','homeController@Music');
```

a

```
public function Music()
{
    $item = music::find(1); //for example
    return view('music',['item'=>$item]);
}
```

that works perfect.
i checked this many ways its because of {vlaues} in urls
it also does not loads styles or js files if an slash get added to end of urls

what is the problem?

Comment: Need to look at the blade templates to see how the page is rendered...

Comment: here is the codes for example and i tested it, it does not load styles when i get it by a url with value in it or add an slash to end of it..but without these it loads styles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the asset() function...

```
<html>
   <head>
       <link href="{{ asset('css/test.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="square"></div>

   <!-- Same for Javascript... -->
   <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i tested it on this too

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="square"></div>
</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: this is not proper way to link styles in blade templates...where is test.css folder in the project?

Comment: its in public/css/test.css folder

Comment: try <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('/')}}/css/test.css">